# Active Directory AND Workgroup on a single computer

Tags: active-directory, workgroup

I'm just wondering if there is a way to have a single computer hooked into both an AD and a Workgroup.

I have a need for my laptop to be able to connect to our AD while I'm in my office, but I need it to be able to connect to a Workgroup when I'm out in the field (I connect to other Windows machines using a crossover cable).

I don't mind having two different accounts setup on the computer if it means I can accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still connect to workgroup resources while your PC is a domain member. Resource access is controlled by each individual workgroup PC, so you'll need either completely open shares, the knowledge of a security principle on the remote workgroup PC or an identical account on your local PC to use passthrough authentication. It's all the same whether your PC is a domain member or not.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't realize it was a permissions thing and not an AD thing.

Comment: Oh what a tangled web we weave when first we practice to understand permissions.

Comment: In my scenario I am actually running XBMC as a media player for a local church.  It can be controlled via HTTP over the lan.  We have multiple sites at our church and some are on AD and some are not... so I need the connection to always work.  Some computers get their IP via DHCP, and others are manually set to 10.10.10.* and hooked together over a Crossover Cable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, and it's not neccessary for the reasons Nonapeptide stated. You need connectivity at the physical and network layers to begin with and then you can make use of network resources via one of the methods stated in Non's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar questions

[workgroup and domain should not be on the same network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/158876/workgroup-and-domain-should-not-be-on-the-same-network)