# workgroup and domain should not be on the same network?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, domain, workgroup

["A workgroup and domain should not be on the same network if it is then you have a problem. (Don't tell me any reson why a WG and DM should be on same network I don't care!)"](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/unable-to-join-xp-to-a-domain/41414.html)

Why? What are the CONs and PROs?

Comment: What a load of garbage.

Comment: Note that forum post is from 2002, and references a Win 2000 domain. Hopefully the vast majority of people are running at least 2003 DCs, ideally with AD and DNS linked, in which case AD is resolved via straight to DNS/DHCP and workgroup just queries the local subnet.

Comment: Please help us in building a clean knowledge base. So, don't use the answer box to comment or add details to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a workgroup and a Windows domain have the same name, and are on the same network then you'll have name resolution problems when looking for the domain.

If the names are different there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How so? I have a domain and a workgroup at home with the same name and have no problems. I do this so that I can browse all machines from the network. My workgroup doesn't cause problems for my domain and my domain doesn't cause problems for my workgroup.

Comment: Yeaah, I also was in doubt because domain and workgroup names are resolved quite differently and independently

Comment: I know that there used to be master browser issues because the machines in the workgroup could try and take over as the master browser for the domain.  This may have been fixed by name.  With a small domain you may not see the problems if they haven't been fixed by Microsoft.